# Interface Joomla with other site

Tags: php, session, cookies, joomla

I want to interface my Joomla site with other site using the COOKIE
So that when some user login to my site, he/she will automatically get access to the private pages from other site by checking the COOKIE/SESSION

Is this possible, can this be done with some ready-made extensions
OR If there is any other better way to accomplish this

Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Technically this is possible, but it depends on a number of details, e.g. are both sites on the same host or available under the same hostname, can they share files or a database connectiion etc. pp..

Answer (score 0):

it is possible with third party API

For example login with [twittter] (http://www.matpal.com/2010/12/login-with-twitter-api-in-php.html)